# Getting values in servlet from two different forms

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to get two values from a jsp page to a servlet, but both are in separate forms:

Drop-down selector:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/helloServlet" method="post">
    <button class="dropbtn" type="submit" value="test" name="curr_val" id="dropbtn">Choose a Value</button>
</form>
```

Menu buttons:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/helloServlet" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="button" class="demobtn">Menu button 1</button>
    <button type="submit" name="button" class="demobtn">Menu button 2</button>
    <button type="submit" name="button" class="expbtn">Menu button 3</button>
    ...
```

Is it possible to get the value from "Drop-down selector" when I press a "Menu" button? Or do I have to have everything wrapped in one form?

Comment: One form at a time! Simply you can store the previous form submit in session/cookies/HTML 5 storage until next form submit. Or just use one form instead of two and use js OR Ajax with combined inputs and send it at once to servlet.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that might do it for you:

**1-** If you could put some `id`'s into your forms like form1 with `id="form1"` and form2 with `id="form2"`, you can do something like:

HTML:

`<input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="submitForms()" />`

JS function:

```
submitForms = function(){
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    document.getElementById("form2").submit();
}
```

**2-** If you could put `name` into your forms, you could do something like this:

```
submitForms = function(){
    document.forms["form1"].submit();
    document.forms["form2"].submit();
}
```

**3-** If you cannot modify the `HTML` and are fine with submitting all the forms on the very `JSP`, you can do something like:

```
$('form').submit();
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, only the second form is sent

Comment: So which approach did you take?

Comment: I'm trying async post with ajax

Comment: No i meant did you put `id`'s into your `form` tags? Or using the 3rd approach of my answer.